# Store pre generated files on Android device and access them using JNI

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have 4 files that I want to put on a /db directory and access those files using JNI functions. I don't want to create files and folders programatically, I already have the 4 **binary** files that I want to read/write from JNI code. My question is, how can I store those pre generated files on the device (maybe on the app directory) and then access them using their path?

```
    jint Java_com_example_nativeexample_MainActivity_getData(JNIEnv* env, jobject javaThis) {

    jint error_code = SUCCESS;

    error_code = readData([directory]+"db/file1.indx", [directory]+"db/file2.dat");

    return error_code;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store them in the app's private file area.  You can get the file name from [Context.getFilesDir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir()).  You can either pass the Context object down and make the call from JNI, or pass the pathname into your JNI code during initialization.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but what do I have to do to put those 4 binary files in the app private file area?

Comment: Read them from wherever they're coming from, and write them to files in that area.  You can add them to your APK file as assets and just unpack them, or download them from a web site if you don't want to ship them with the APK.